# JQuery Add/Remove Class Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Building a simple `Multilevel` push menu based on CSS classes, It has no javascript animations and runs on CSS transform/transitions. It works fine on every part other than toggling the is-open classes.

1. When a user clicks on a link, it should first remove the .is-open class. Then add it so the animation activates.
2. If i say change the .is-open class in the second stage to `.addClass("foo");` it has no problem removing the .is-open class and adding the .foo class. So i'm wondering what the problem is with this section of the code.

You can find the code here http://jsbin.com/EjUQ/2/

On the demo you'll find that menus without a `submenu` load nothing. This is the correct behavior. The problem I'm having is that I would like the Menu to close before opening a new one. So removing the `.is-open` class then applying it again.

e.g

Link 1, 4,7 don't have submenu's so nothing with open on `click/touch`, clicking the menu button will prompt nothing to happen. This is the correct behaviour.

Link 2,3,5,6 have submenu's, so it opens on click/touch and the menu button will toggle the menu to open/close.

Hopefully someone can point me the direction of what i'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should utilize the [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/transitionend) event. So that you listen for the animation to complete before adding the 'is-open' class back to the sidebar and content. Ex:

```
sidebar.one('transitionend', function() {
    sidebar.addClass("is-open");
    content.addClass("is-open");
});
```

Now, what I have here isn't perfect, but I believe it conveys the concept: http://jsbin.com/EjUQ/9

Comment: that example ( http://jsbin.com/EjUQ/9 ) doesn't work for me - the menus close but do not open.

Comment: There are multiple events that have to be listened for (due to browser adoption). See the transitionend link above for reference. You can also find plugins that will handle all of the browser differences, such as: https://github.com/ai/transition-events. I only did a quick version for webkit.

Comment: Andi, it's because ArrayKnight editted the code in Chrome/Safari so it has a webkit prefix.

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification.  So basically, it's not possible to keep this JS-free as the OP had tried?

Comment: You're not using JS animations if that's what you're asking. You're still utilizing the same CSS transformations that you had originally. You're just listening for when those transformations complete. This isn't really adding any JS that you're not already using. You're just using jQuery event binding, like $(".submenu li").on( 'click touchstart', ...)

Comment: I could get the menu to work on radio/checkbox hack using :target. But JS free doesn't seem logical to me anymore. As the majority of interaction requires a reaction of some kind, for the user. The transitionend seems ideal because the Gecko, Trident, Webkit, Blink and Presto support it with the correct vendor prefixs.

Comment: there is a massive debate about JS animation vs CSS animations. I find that JS animations are often snappy/jerky as they don't fall inline with the 60fps most devices run and don't use hardware acceleration effectively enough.